# Basic CSS Issue, properties changing in multiple classes?

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit of a novice with CSS and currently banging my head against the table trying to figure out whats wrong with my code. 
The HTML:

```
<div id="loginForm">
    <span class="dottedLink"><a href="resetlogin">Recover login details</a></span><br>
    <span class="dottedLink"><a href="signup">Create an account</a></span> 
</div>
<div id="mainpageSplashImage"></div><br>   
<div id="titleDesciption">This is the Title</div>  
<div id="registerButtonPlacement"><a href="signup" class="linkButton">Register</a></div>
```

The CSS:

```
.dottedLink {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: .9em;
}
.dottedLink a, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #0099CC;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
.dottedLink a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: #990000;
}
.linkButton { 
    background: #CC0000;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.linkButton a, a:active, a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.linkButton:hover { 
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #CC0000;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The main problem being, I cannont change the 'color' property (and ONLY the 'color' property) of 'dottedLink' without also changing the color property of 'linkButton'. Meaning, if i change the color of one class, the color o the other class also automatically changes. I've tested this in other browsers, and it seems to only be happening in firefox and I don't know why. Please help, this is so frustrating

Comment: you could remove the `a` tag from the `.dottedLink` class in css, maybe that might solve the issue

Comment: What color is it changing to?  It might be "visited" already.  In your line `.linkButton a, a:active, a:visited` you have commas separating a few different elements.  one of them being `a:visited`.  This is probably the color you're seeing on any link that has been visited

Comment: Semantically it might me more useful to set those classes on the links themselves and not their container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** The way you think it works...

Explanation: Consider this code.

```
.dottedLink a, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #0099CC;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

it will select the `a` tags under `.dottedLink` class as per `.dottedLink a`, it selects all the `a` tags as per `a:visited` and `a:visited`.  And hence you are not targetting only the `a` tags under the desired class element but all the `a` tags. So the mentioned styles is applies to all `a` tags in your page

Continuing the issue. You have this code

```
.linkButton a, a:active, a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

which again is the same case.. chooses all the `a` tags and applies that style.

**Solution:**  is to refactor your code to target specific `a` tags like

```
.dottedLink a, .dottedLink a:visited, .dottedLink a:active {
```

and

```
  .linkButton a, .linkButton a:active, .linkButton a:visited {
```

**Remember** each `,` separated selector acts on its own and is not linked with its preceding selectors as you think..

So this example

```
.linkButton a, a:active, a:visited {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

is equivalent to

```
.linkButton a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:active{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.a:visited {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Hope you get the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
.dottedLink a, .dottedLink a:visited, .dottedLink a:active {
    color: #0099CC;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

instead of

```
.dottedLink a, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #0099CC;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

Do the same for `.linkButton`. Now any change on `.dottedLink` won't affect `.linkButton` and vice versa. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With your html the way it is and the CSS the way it is, You're probably seeing the `:visited` color on your link.  Even if you were to change the color of the `<span>`, the link has it's own color which would override the span (since it's a child of the span).

The way to fix this is to specify the color of the link, rather than the span.  You can do this by using the `>` CSS selector.  Also by separating the specific element.

Your line here:

```
.dottedLink a, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #0099CC;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

could make more sense by looking at it this way:

```
.dottedLink a, 
a:visited, 
a:active {
    color: #0099CC;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

This should tell you that when you change `.dottedLink a`, you're also changing **ANY** `a:visited` and `a:active`.

A better way to change the color of just the `.dottedLink a` is to separate it out of that block.

```
.dottedLink a, a:visited, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
.dottedLink > a { /*This greater-than symbol means 'the direct child of' */
    color:#000000; /*Whatever color*/
}
a:visited, a:active {
    color: #0099CC;
}
```

Now you have the global dotted border on all `a` links AND the control to make them all separate colors.